# I don't understand why there is such a huge vote discrepancy between these two answers

Tags: support

Answer 1: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7404/6675 |  **24 upvotes**

> As Kevin noted, Harry was given a special exemption. From Book 1:
>
> > "He's just the build for a Seeker, too," said Wood, now walking around
> >     Harry and staring at him. "Light -- speedy -- we'll have to get him a
> >     decent broom, Professor -- a Nimbus Two Thousand or a Cleansweep
> >     Seven, I'd say."
> >
> > "I shall speak to Professor Dumbledore and see if we can't bend the
> >     first-year rule. Heaven knows, we need a better team than last year.
> >     Flattened in that last match by Slytherin, I couldn't look Severus
> >     Snape in the face for weeks...." [ this was Prof. McGonagall speaking
> >     - DVK ]

Answer 2: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7381/6675 
|  **2 upvotes**

> When McGonagall was telling Wood about Harry (or somewhere very close
>   to that), she said she'd talk to Dumbledore about getting an exception
>   for him.
>
> > "He's just the build for a Seeker, too," said Wood, now walking around Harry and staring at him. "Light -- speedy -- we'll have to get
> >     him a decent broom, Professor -- a Nimbus Two Thousand or a Cleansweep
> >     Seven, I'd say."
> >
> > "**I shall speak to Professor Dumbledore and see if we can't bend the first-year rule.** Heaven knows, we need a better team than last year.
> >     Flattened in that last match by Slytherin, I couldn't look Severus
> >     Snape in the face for weeks..."

Answer 2 has a whopping 22 LESS votes than Answer 1.  Answer 2 has also been posted a month before Answer 1. Even Answer 1 references Answer 2.  Yet, currently, they say literally the same exact thing, with the exception of the opening sentence, one that states which book the quote is from, the other answer narrating the context of the quote.

I don't really understand this at all...

Comment: May I be the first to complement you on your choice of username.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The difference is because you're looking at the *final* edit, rather than the initial answer.

If you compare DVK's [first effort](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/7404/revisions) (basically unchanged) with Kevin's [first effort](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/7381/revisions) (massively changed) you can very easily see why one got more votes than the other.

[image]

Comment: Good sleuthing.

Comment: @Pureferret - Thank you Watson, now please fetch me my violin and some cocaine.

Comment: @Richard - You're both about to experience a skillet-beating from Mrs. Hudson for getting coke dust on cleaned-up room